# Two similar objects on the same page

Tags: javascript, notation, object-literal

I am working my way through a JavaScript book and am currently looking at creating objects with Literal Notation.

I am given this code:

```
var hotel = {
name: 'Quay',
rooms: 40,
booked:25,
checkAvailability: function() {
return this.rooms - this.booked;
 }
}

var hotelName = document.getElementById('hotel-name');
hotelName.textContent = hotel.name;

var freeRooms = document.getElementById('free-rooms');
freeRooms.textContent = hotel.checkAvailability();
```

I understand this perfectly fine.

It then tells me *'If you had two objects on the same page, you would create each one using the same notation but store them in variables with different names.'*

I've tried to create this in JSFiddel but seem to be failing and I'm not sure why. Could anybody please post up a quick example and explaination. That'd be really helpful.

EDIT:: I am not sure whether it is telling me that I would write another object entirly or put some variables inside the existing object that link to name/rooms etc..

Thanks in advance.

Reference: John Duckett - JavaScript and JQuery

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Should work exactly like that sentence says, ie: `var obj = {}, obj2 = {}`

Comment: It _sounds_ like the answer might be in the book itself. Maybe something you missed before this point. Or did not yet read ahead enough. In any case, it's not very clear what this question is about.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean it isnt working, Im just looking for an explination as to how it would be written, Im just struggling to understand the explination.

Comment: @11 - Oh, it means if you had another hotel, you could declare it the exact same way, but with a different variable name, ie: `var hotel = { ... }, hotel2 = { ... }`

Comment: @tymeJV ah I see, so Id write another object entirely? as opposed to adding variables inside the existing object...

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you want (what do you not understand). Definitely you can create two objects on the same page with different names. You can create even more than two :)

Comment: @impregnable fiend I wasnt sure if its saying edit existing object with new var's or create a name one with new var name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this as a class, so you can reuse the Hotel object by typing `new Hotel(name, rooms, booked)`

```js
function Hotel(name, rooms, booked) {
  this.name = name;
  this.rooms = rooms;
  this.booked = booked;
}

Hotel.prototype = {
  checkAvailability: function() {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  }
}

var hotel = new Hotel('Quay', 40, 25);
var hotel2 = new Hotel('Hotel2', 50, 45);

var hotelName = document.getElementById('hotel-name-1');
hotelName.textContent = hotel.name;

var freeRooms = document.getElementById('free-rooms-1');
freeRooms.textContent = hotel.checkAvailability();

var hotelName = document.getElementById('hotel-name-2');
hotelName.textContent = hotel2.name;

var freeRooms = document.getElementById('free-rooms-2');
freeRooms.textContent = hotel2.checkAvailability();
```

```html
<div id='hotel-name-1'></div>
<div id='free-rooms-1'></div>
<br>
<div id='hotel-name-2'></div>
<div id='free-rooms-2'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can store an object that is the same in structure, but with different values. Let me explain this by wrapping your example object into a function that pumps out different hotels, with the same structure

```js
function hotel(name, rooms, booked) {
  var hotel = {
    name: name,
    rooms: rooms,
    booked: booked,
    checkAvailability: checkAvailability
  };

  return hotel;
}

//lets seperate the checkAvailability function from the function so it can be reused. 
function checkAvailability() {
  return this.rooms - this.booked;
}

var hotel1 = hotel("quay", 40, 25);
var hotel2 = hotel("Ocean View", 50, 20);
console.log(hotel1);
console.log(hotel2);
console.log(hotel1.checkAvailability());
console.log(hotel2.checkAvailability());
```

Comment: Hi Mouser, quick question, when you write..name: name or rooms: rooms, does Javascript automatically replace the second 'name' or 'rooms' with the arguement of the parameter? Jope this makes sense, new to all this lingo..

Comment: Yes it does, it takes the arguments, supplied within the function and assigns them to the object. In the end it returns the object to the variable with the assigned properties.

Answer (score 0):

And one more example using your Hotel with different instances through es6-classes:

```
class Hotel {
  constructor(name, rooms, booked) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rooms = rooms;
    this.booked = booked;
  }

  get checkAvailability() {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  }
}

const hotelOne = new Hotel('First', 44, 21),
      hotelTwo = new Hotel('Second', 21, 5);
console.log(hotelOne.checkAvailability);
console.log(hotelTwo.checkAvailability);
```